# Is the City of London fully subject to the Public Sector Equality Duty?

Tags: equality-act-2010, city-of-london

Some parts of the City of London Corporation function like a public body (eg the City Fund) while others (e.g. City’s Cash) somehow do not.

For the purposes of the Equality Act’s PSED, is it a Public Sector entity?

Comment: What does "fully subject to" mean? In its capacity as a local authority, port authority and police authority, the City of London is subject to the PSED.

Comment: By fully subject to, I mean in all of its aspects and capacities. So in which capacities is it not subject to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The City of London Corporation has public functions, private functions and charitable functions.

With regard to the [Public Sector Equality Duty (PSED)](https://www.equalityhumanrights.com/en/advice-and-guidance/public-sector-equality-duty), the City's public functions are in scope and its private functions and charitable functions are out of scope.

- In the City's [capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacity_(law)) as a local authority, it performs the functions of a local authority and (in general) is subject to the laws that govern local authorities (including PSED).
- In the City's capacity as a police authority, it performs the functions of a police authority and (in general) is subject to the laws that govern police authorities (including PSED).
- In the City's capacity as a port authority, it performs the functions of a port authority and (in general) is subject to the laws that govern port authorities (including PSED).